# Element LinearLayout doesn't have required attribute layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout

Each TextView and Button as well as the LinearLayout tag complain

```
'layout_height' attribute should be defined

'layout_width' attribute should be defined
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/rest/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/main_title" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/continue_label" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_label" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/exit_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm running Android Studio 1.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `xmlns` attribute to be:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

`/res/` not `/rest/`